# Getting first object from list performance

Tags: java

Which piece of code executes faster in Java?

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object firstObject = null;
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    firstObject = list.get(0);
}
```

or

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object firstObject = null;
try {
    firstObject = list.get(0);
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
}
```

Comment: Try running a test. Execute the code lots of times and time it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: With pieces of code like you provided, it doesn't really matter, they will both be super fast.  It would be better to use the empty list check however, rather than relying on an exception to handle empty list access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: [Exception thrown](https://www.quora.com/How-expensive-is-the-try-catch-block-in-Java-in-terms-of-performance) tend to be relatively more expensive  handle

Answer (score -1):

I think the first approach would be better. Since we filtering the list before Getting the element from the list. The second statement list. get(0) will not execute.

Considering the second approach, It may throw exception.

Considering the run times, both execute at the same time.

Comment: This is not a good answer.  Either provide proof of your response or add a comment to better understand the question.